# Quadratic programming in Haskell

Tags: optimization, haskell, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

Are there any Haskell bindings for [quadratic programming libraries](http://www.numerical.rl.ac.uk/qp/qp.html)?

If not, which one should I write *simplified* bindings for assuming I cannot avoid needing one?  Is there a reasonably canonically favored open source library for this?

Comment: Looks like there's some scipy solvers, or OpenOpt. You might be able to use them via the "missingpy" package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There probably isn't.  Way back in the day I had to whip up my own linear programming bindings -- [glpk-hs](https://github.com/lowasser/glpk-hs) -- but I doubt anything's come along for quadratic programming since then.